# Start MongoDB as a Daemon without having to write log

Tags: mongodb

Is there a remote (ssh) way to simulate the:

```
mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log
```

without the logging part? If I ommit the logpath mongod will complain.

I'm having it running on a RaspberryPi and I'd like to turn the logging off to maximize the SD card lifespan.

Comment: I assume you are running on linux? You can install from repo which will install a rc/init script into your distro and allow mongod to be run on startup, check the install guides on the mongodb site for more info on that. Or if as your question states you actually want to turn off logging you can set the: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongod/#cmdoption-mongod--diaglog

Comment: I'm running that fork: https://github.com/RickP/mongopi , even with diaglog set to 0 I have the connections logged.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Redirect logging to `/dev/null` instead of a file:

```
mongod --fork --logpath /dev/null
```

Comment: I didn't know about /dev/null thanks. But how can I make sure that writing to it doesn't fire a write operation to the SD?

Comment: Because [/dev/null](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/null) is a separate bit-bucket device that just discards all data written to it.